# Pandas How to Align Two Columns in a DataFrame and NaN empty cells

Tags: arrays, pandas, dataframe, nan

I'm using Python 3.8.8

I have a DataFrame structured like this:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 7 |
| 4 | 7 |
| 5 | 8 |

and an array:

C = [3, 4, 7]

I would like to add an array "C" as a new column to the DataFrame. The problem is this array has a different length of index than the df. I would like to make up for the difference in length in C by filling the empty cells with NaNs. My desired result would look something like:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | NaN |
| 1 | 2 | NaN |
| 2 | 1 | 3 |
| 3 | 7 | 4 |
| 4 | 7 | 7 |
| 5 | 8 | NaN |

What I am looking for specifically is a way to add C starting at a specific index of the df, but I don't know how to work around the discrepancy between the length of the df and array.

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 2):

To get around the problem of 'different length' when putting your list into the dataframe, you can convert it to a `pandas` `series`. Once you do that, you can easily add it to your dataframe with the rest of the values being filled with `np.nan`.

In your case, you can specifically also set the `index` when you convert your C `list` to a `series`, which you can then assign to your `dataframe`. [Pandas nature to align data on indices](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/dsintro.html#intro-to-data-structures) will place the series on the right index

Consider using the code below:

```
c = pd.Series([3, 4, 7],index=[2,3,4])
df['C'] = c
```

prints:

```
   A  B    0
0  0  1  NaN
1  1  2  NaN
2  2  1  3.0
3  3  7  4.0
4  4  7  7.0
5  5  8  NaN
```

Renaming `0` should be trivial.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for!

Comment: You don't need the merge here.... pandas will align automatically on indexes.   `c = pd.Series([3, 4, 7],index=[2,3,4])` then `df['C'] = c` [data alignment is intrinsic](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/dsintro.html#intro-to-data-structures)

Comment: Absolutely. Thanks for the correction and the link @Scott. I have updated accordingly.